# How get class object keys in flutter

Tags: flutter

I created one class as Student.

```
class Student{
  int id;
  String name;

  Student({this.id,this.name});
}
```

Now I need to print key - id and name

Comment: overide toString

Comment: When I override .toString() output will come like this "Instance of 'Student'"

Answer (score 1):

For a proper way to do that you could check my code below. This is how to override the toString().

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

@immutable
class Student{
  final int id;
  final String name;

  const Student({required this.id,required this.name});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Student{id: $id, name: $name}';
  }
  
}
```

Then you could print like this:

```
    Student student = const Student(id: 1, name: 'John');
    print(student);
    print(student.id);
    print(student.name);
```

Comment: I need key name list only, not value

Comment: add the toMap()  "  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }" then you could => print(student.toMap().keys);

Answer (score 0):

Create a `toJson` method inside your Student class, and print out your parameters.

```
class Student{
  int id;
  String name;

  Student({this.id,this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
       if(id!= null) "Id": id,
       if(name != null)  "Name": name,
      };
}
```

then,

```
Student exampleStudent= Student(id: '001', name: "john"); //feed values
  print(exampleStudent.toJson());
```

Comment: I need only key (Dynamically)

Comment: I see. Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075238/14577209) might help you to print the object keys. keep in mind that this is a workaround.